# how can I insert an element to Numpy matrix by row and column indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to create a matrix with Numpy, but I need to add every element by its row and column indices.

for example:

```
my_matrix = np.matrix(np.zeros((5, 5))) 
my_matrix.insert(row_index=2, column_index=1, value=10)

output:
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [10., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How can I do that?

Comment: my_matrix[2][1] = 10

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa it replaces all elements in row[2] to 10

Comment: If you do `my_matrix[2] = 10`, Then it would replace all the elements in the 3rd row (row with index `2`).

Comment: If you do `my_matrix[2][1] = 10`, Then it would replace only the element in 3rd row (row index `2`) and 2nd column (column index `1`)

Comment: it trows an exception, it gives row[2] but can not access to element. IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa don't use chained indexing, it creates an intermediate copy and is inefficient.  `my_matrix[2, 1] = 10`.  Or, for a minor performance improvement if you are going to be setting lots of individual elements: `my_matrix.itemset((2, 1), 10)`

Comment: Got it. Was not aware of intermediate copies in chained indexing.

Comment: Chained indexing on a `np.matrix` is wrong.  On a regular numpy array it should work, but `arr[1, 2] = 10` is better style`

Comment: Why are you using `np.matrix`?

Comment: Don't use `np.matrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to add or insert values? 
The add function that you mentioned is used as an element-wise addition.

Example:

```
np.add([1, 2], [2, 3])
Out[41]: array([3, 5])
```

If you really want to create a matrix a matrix by inserting values with column and row indices, create the matrix first and insert your values afterwards.

```
number_rows = 10
number_cols = 20
arr = np.empty((number_rows, number_cols))
arr[2, 1] = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `np.matrix` is discouraged, if not actually deprecated.  It is rarely needed, except for some backward compatibility cases.

```
In [1]: arr = np.zeros((5,5))                                                                    
In [2]: arr                                                                                      
Out[2]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [3]: mat = np.matrix(arr)                                                                     
In [4]: mat                                                                                      
Out[4]: 
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Indexing one row of `arr` produces a 1d array

```
In [5]: arr[2]                                                                                   
Out[5]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Indexing one row of `mat` produces a 2d matrix, with shape (1,5)

```
In [6]: mat[2]                                                                                   
Out[6]: matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

We can access an element in the 1d array:

```
In [7]: arr[2][1]                                                                                
Out[7]: 0.0
```

but this indexing of the `mat` tries to access a row, and gives an error:

```
In [8]: mat[2][1]                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-212ad5378f8e> in <module>
----> 1 mat[2][1]
 ...
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

In both cases it is better to access an element with the tuple syntax, rather than the chained one:

```
In [9]: arr[2,1]                                                                                 
Out[9]: 0.0
In [10]: mat[2,1]                                                                                
Out[10]: 0.0
```

This indexing also works for setting values.  But try to avoid iterating to set individual values.  Try to find ways of creating the whole array with the desired values directly, with whole array methods, not iteration.